# Saving dataframes as .Rdata files using a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, save, rdata

I'm trying to save a bunch of data frames as .RData files. Right now I approach it like this:

```
save(Dataset_1, file = "Hypothesis1/Dataset1.RData")
save(Dataset_2, file = "Hypothesis1/Dataset2.RData")
save(Dataset_3, file = "Hypothesis1/Dataset3.RData")
```

This works, but I would like to save these dataframes using a for loop. I was thinking of something like this:

```
for (i in 1:11){
  save(paste0("Dataset_",i), file = "paste0("Hypothesis1/Dataset",i, ".RData")" 
}
```

unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working out, does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: why this is quoted `"paste0("Hypothesis1/Dataset",i, ".RData")"`?

Comment: It seems that you have quoted "paste0(" try : save(paste0("Dataset_",i), file = paste0("Hypothesis1/Dataset",i, ".RData")

Comment: if I remove the quotes and try

for (i in 1:11) {
  save(paste0("Dataset_",i), file = paste0("Hypothesis1/Dataset",i, ".RData")) 
}

I get object ‘paste0("Dataset_", i)’ not found

Comment: Just be sure to use the `list=` parameter with `save()` if you are passing the name of the object as a character string rather than passing the value itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the name of your dataset outside of `save()` as it evaluates the first arguments as character or symbols and functions would not be evaluated.

Also, you need to get rid of quotations around the second `paste0` and close your parentheses for `save()` which look like a typos.

```
for (i in 1:11){
    dbname <- paste0("Dataset_",i)
  save(dbname, file = paste0("Hypothesis1/Dataset",i, ".RData"))
}
```

Better approach would be using `apply` functions, listing your datasets name using `ls`, and passing them into `save` as character using `list = ...` argument.

```
lapply(ls(pattern="Dataset[0-9]+"), function(x) save(list = x, file = paste0("Hypothesis1/",x,".RData")))
```

Comment: Really you should probably use the `list=` parameter rather than creating an unnecessary variable: `save(list = paste0("Dataset_", i), file = paste0("Hypothesis1/Dataset", i, ".RData"))`

Comment: @MrFlick working on an `apply` solution. This is just to illustrate where OP went wrong in their own solution, not the best though.

Comment: thank you, it makes sense now :)